# Execute something when a stream file finished to download with ASPNET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASPNET MVC 3 and when a link is clicked in the View I'm returning from the controller a FileResult (it's taken from a Stream, not a physical file).
What I want to achieve is do something when the file finishes to download. Is there any possibility to do it? As I can't write anything right now after the return File....

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Comment: There is a difference between when the stream completes writting ie. FileResult.WriteFile method completes vs when the client finishes downloading the item.  Do you care if the download actually finished at the client?

Comment: Perform the file download in ajax (so you don't have to do anything after the return FileResult(), then on the client side do whatever you want in the success() callback.

Comment: @jsobo, Yes, I'd like to show a message when the file is completely sent to the client and completely downloaded.

Comment: @BigMike, Would that popup the Save dialog without redirecting the user somewhere else?
I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @polonskyg no, you should handle the save in your js callback, so it can be a bit risky. No save dialog, you probably will end up saving silently somewhere. Better use a hidden iframe.

Comment: you can't really do it... at least easily.. one thing that you could do is have multiple (ajax) requests going simultaneously.  First you make a call via ajax to get a download ID.. then you use that id to start a iframe download.  Then you make another ajax call perhaps using a timer to continously poll the server asking about the progress of the download.  It is really complicated and probably not worth it.  One thing you could do is fiddler sites that do it the way you want it and see what they are doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create your own file result or derive an existing one:

```
public class MyFileStreamResult : FileStreamResult 
{
    // [.. constructors here ..]


    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) 
    {
        base.ExecuteResult(context);

        // do something here
    }
}
```

Then result it from your action:

```
return new MyFileStreamResult(myStream, "application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: I actually had the exact code ready to paste into my answer when yours popped up... (my comment was // your extra code here ... instead of "do something"  ... ;-)

Comment: @jgauffin, When is the // do something here code executed? both in server and client sides?
Thanks!

Comment: Server side when everything has been sent

Comment: @jgauffin, I'm marking your reply as the correct answer thank you! But can you please show me how to send or example an alert there? I mean, I don't know how to send something to the client where the //do something here is.
Thank you again. Guillermo

Comment: You can't with plain HTTP. You need to have a websocket or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have no way of knowing when the file has downloaded or if it even downloaded successfully.

One solution is to display a 'You are now downloading' or 'your download will begin in a few seconds' page, and use a hidden iframe or JavaScript to begin the file download. The page can act as if the page was a success.